# Find the area bounded by $x= at^{2}$ and $y = 2at$ from $t=1$ to $t=2$

Tags: area

Find the area bounded by $x= at^{2}$ and $y = 2at$ from $t=1$ to $t=2$

I tried to solve this by integrating 
$\int_{1}^2 y \frac{dx}{dt} dt$

$\int_{1}^2 (4a^{2}t^{2}) dt$

$= (28/3)a^{2}$

What is wrong with my attempt$?$

Answer is given $(56/3)a^{2}$

Comment: Well, for one, your integration is wrong: the antiderivative of your integral (taking $a$ constant) is

$$\int 4at^2 dt = 4a \int t^2 dt = \frac 4 3 at^3 + C$$

No $a^3$ anywhere. (Also $dx/dt = 2at$ so you'd actually have $a^2$.) Of course the problem lies deeper but I figured it worth noting.

Comment: @Mathsaddict: How is that a bounded region?

Comment: I think we're supposed to assume it is bounded on the left by $x=a$ and on the right by $x=4a$?

Comment: And on the bottom?

Comment: Ah true - $x$ axis presumably.

Comment: That should be stated.

Comment: I don't disagree on that.

Comment: For OP: if you get tripped up on these, just straight up solve $y$ in terms of $x$ and fix your limits of integration. Then see if you can find where your mistake might have come from when working with the implicit $t$ integral.

Comment: @CameronWilliams This question is given in a book exactly as I stated here. I googled this problem before asking and there are many other sites I could find for the solution of same question. But I didn't get how did they take the limits for solution

Comment: @Mathsaddict: Assuming the lower boundary was intended as the $x$-axis, your answer is correct. Note: answer keys can be wrong.

Comment: Somewhere I saw, that this is a parabola and limits were from $x=a$ to $x=2a$ and from $y= - \sqrt{4ax}$ to $y= \sqrt{4ax}$

Comment: It's not a full parabola. Note that if $a > 0$, then $x,y$ are both positive when $1\le t\le2$, so you only get the upper half of the parabola. Presumably, that's where whoever made the answer key got it wrong.

Comment: Oh geez this is a case of someone taking a square root and using both solutions when both are not necessarily correct in the context of the broader problem..

Comment: @EeveeTrainer $y \cdot (dx/dt) = 2at \cdot 2at = 4a^2t^2$?

Comment: @AhmedHossam Yes, that's correct? Not sure what you're trying to show/ask me. If you're wondering why my post has $a$ not $a^2$, OP's post had $a$ before an edit, but that's all I can guess

Comment: That must be it then, an edit.

Answer (score 4):

Your answer is just [fine](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ParaArea.aspx), because $$\int_{1}^{2} 4a^2 ~dt = \int_{a}^{4a} 2a\sqrt{\frac{x}{a}}~ dx  = 28a^2/3$$
is the area between the parametric curve and the $x(t)$-axis.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Hint: You can also use an explicit form of your function:
$$t=\sqrt{\frac{x}{a}}=t$$ so
$$y=2a\sqrt{\frac{x}{a}}$$

Comment: Ok, thanks, just corrected!

Answer (score 0):

The curve is a parabola y^2 = 4aX  area will be twice the area under curve y=sqrt.(4ax) from X= a to X = 4a and x axis answer is 56 a^2 / 3

Comment: $$\int_{x=a}^{x=4a}\sqrt{4ax}~dx=\int_{x=a}^{x=4a}2\sqrt{ax}~dx=\int_{x=a}^{x=4a}2a\sqrt{\frac{x}{a}}~dx=28a^2/3$$